# Present UIWebview on top on currently displayed view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm trying to modally display a UIWebview on top of the currently displayed view controller. The code to popup the webview lives in a static library and has no idea about the view controller hierarchy of the app that it lives in. The code below works for my test cases, but not sure if it would work for all possible view controller hierarchies.

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
UIViewController *presentedVC = [rootViewController presentedViewController];
if (presentedVC) {
    // We have a modally displayed viewcontroller on top of rootViewController.
    if (!presentedVC.isBeingPresented) {
    [presentedVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
        //
    }];
} else {
    rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
        //
    }];
}
```

Does the presentedViewController always give the currently visible view controller?

Comment: Hm, if this works Id be surprised. Unless I'm going insane the keyWindow returns the current visible window that was last called to `makeKeyAndVisisble`. 

To get the current presented view controller it all depends on your hierarchy. If you have a modal screen thats it, if not and you have nav controller as the root youll have to look at the top of the stack.

I think itll be pretty tough to find the top view controller given so many ways to set up the navigation layers..

Comment: I think you'll want to pass the current view controller in as a property to your library.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Thats definitely an option, but I was trying to make this transparent for the developer using the static library.

Comment: @feliun I added a check for presentedVC being nil. It seems like presentedVC is always nil if there is no modally displayed view controller on top of rootViewController.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is to display the `UIWebView` modally on top of whatever View Controller is displayed in your app, you don't need the "topmost" one. Getting the Root View Controller will suffice. I do this all the time whenever I want to present a View on top of everything else.
You only need a reference to the root view controller in your library:

```
self.rootVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

Having this reference you have two options now:

The first one is to use `UIViewController`'s method `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to display another View Controller which will contain your `UIWebView`

The second option is to fake the modal view controller by adding a subview that covers the entire screen, has a (semi)transparent background, and contains the view you want to display "modally". Here is an example:

```
@interface FakeModalView : UIView // the *.h file

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *background; // this will cover the entire screen

-(void)show; // this will show the fake modal view
-(void)close; // this will close the fake modal view

@end

@interface FakeModalView () // the *.m file

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootVC; 

@end

@implementation FakeViewController
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize background = _background;
@synthesize rootVC = _rootVC;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        [self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]]; 
        _rootVC = self.rootVC = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] retain];
        self.frame = _rootVC.view.bounds; // to make this view the same size as the application

        _background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [_background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [_background setOpaque:NO];
        [_background setAlpha:0.7]; // make the background semi-transparent

        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(THE_POSITION_YOU_WANT_IT_IN)];

        [self addSubview:_background]; // add the background
        [self addSubview:_webView]; // add the web view on top of it
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc { // remember to release everything

    [_webView release];
    [_background release];
    [_rootVC release];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)show {

    [self.rootVC.view addSubview:self]; // show the fake modal view
}

-(void)close {

    [self removeFromSuperview]; // hide the fake modal view
}

@end
```

If you have any other questions just let me know.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first option (using rootViewController) wont work because you could have a viewcontroller which is already displayed modally on top of the rootViewController. I started with that approach and was getting this warning for the scenario I described above: <PopupViewController: 0x7ce37a0> on <MyRootViewController: 0x798e050> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: I'll try the second option and let you know.